# how can i filter with month from date in a sqlite using content resolver in android studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i have tried this:

```
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            medication_uri,
            null,
            "strftime('%m', "+COLUMN_START_DATE+")" + "=?",
            new String[]{"01"},
            COLUMN_START_DATE+" DESC");
```

and it's not returning anything.

The Code up there is a content resolver the simply translate to a query which is:

```
    select * from TABLE_NAME 
    where strftime('%m', "+COLUMN_START_DATE+") = 01  
    orderBy  COLUMN_START_DATE desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Querying the database with strftime() won' t work because date and time are saved in milliseconds in android sqlite db. So i had to get the milliseconds out of the db then get the month of the milliseconds using:

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date dateDate = new Date(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_START_DATE););
        String startDateMonth = simpleDateFormat.format(dateDate);
```

then i used my startDateMonth to filter my recycler view by month